# "Invalid Message Size" connecting Cosmos DB to Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect Cosmos DB database using Mongoose to my Node JS web app with this code

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const User = require('./model/user')

mongoose
        .connect(
            'mongodb://' +
                process.env.COSMOSDB_HOST +
                ':' +
                process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT +
                '/' +
                process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME +
                '?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb',
            {
                auth: {
                    username: process.env.COSMOSDB_USER,
                    password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD,
                },
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
                retryWrites: false,
            },
        )
        .then(() => console.log('Connection to CosmosDB successful'))
        .catch((err) => console.error('ERRORE: ' + err));

const app = express()
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')})

app.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
        res.render('register')})
  
        

app.post('/register', async(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({status:'ok'})
})


app.listen(9999,() =>{
    console.log('Server up at 9999')
})

module.exports = app
```

but when running it I get the error **MongooseServerSelectionError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Cosmos DB API are you using? Mongoose will only work if you're using the MongoDB API. It won't work when using the SQL API (or Cassandra, or Gremlin, or Table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using mongoose? When you can use `@azure/cosmos`, it should work fine. Mongoose is an ORM for mongodb.

Install `@azure/cosmos`

```
npm install @azure/cosmos --save
```

Then set up config :

```
const config = {
  endpoint: "<Your Azure Cosmos account URI>",
  key: "<Your Azure Cosmos account key>",
  databaseId: "Tasks",
  containerId: "Items",
  partitionKey: { kind: "Hash", paths: ["/category"] }
};

module.exports = config;
```

get connection:

```
const config = require("../config");
const CosmosClient = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;

/*
// This script ensures that the database is setup and populated correctly
*/
async function create(client, databaseId, containerId) {
  const partitionKey = config.partitionKey;

  /**
   * Create the database if it does not exist
   */
  const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({
    id: databaseId
  });
  console.log(`Created database:\n${database.id}\n`);

  /**
   * Create the container if it does not exist
   */
  const { container } = await client
    .database(databaseId)
    .containers.createIfNotExists(
      { id: containerId, partitionKey },
      { offerThroughput: 400 }
    );

  console.log(`Created container:\n${container.id}\n`);
}

module.exports = { create };
```

Create connection:

```
const CosmosClient = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;
const config = require("./config");
const dbContext = require("./data/databaseContext");

const { endpoint, key, databaseId, containerId } = config;

const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });

const database = client.database(databaseId);
const container = database.container(containerId);

// Make sure Tasks database is already setup. If not, create it.
await dbContext.create(client, databaseId, containerId);
```

Now, you can query the DB or create items in it. I would suggest you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-nodejs-get-started) article for all the steps if the above steps are not clear.

Comment: FYI Cosmos DB provides a MongoDB API, which you can use mongoose with. The OP didn't specify which API their particular Cosmos DB instance is using.